# What is boilerplate code?

Tags: architecture, terminology, definition, boilerplate

A coworker had never heard of this, and I couldn't provide a real definition. For me, it's always been an instance of 'I-know-it-when-I-see-it'.

Bonus question, who originated the term?

Comment: As a note, the term boilerplate isn't exclusive to programming. For instance a lawyer may give you a 5 page contract to sign, but most of the contract is boilerplate. Meaning it's the same for everyone that gets that contract, with only a few lines changed here and there.

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but in my company the boilerplate code is the code that operates the boilerplate: open, close, wash, replace, etc...

Comment: I came here because of Laravel's documentation and thought.. "What is this boilerplate-stuff they're talking about?". After reading some answers I thought this directly related wiki-page shows insight on the matter as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code

Comment: I heard the term recently, So I am curious to know if I can call them as plugin or module for the programming languages.

Comment: By the way, is "boilerplate" really a term or a slang word?

Answer (score 280):

"boilerplate code" is any seemingly repetitive code that shows up again and again in order to get some result that seems like it ought to be much simpler.

It's a subjective definition.

The term comes from "boilerplate" in the newspaper industry: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_(text))

Comment: The idea behind multiproperties in OOP is to reduce boilerplate, so when applied properly it can be reduced quite a bit.

Comment: It is also said it, it come from steel industry, where steel plates are used int boilers

Answer (score 88):

Boilerplate code means a piece of code which can be used over and over again. On the other hand, anyone can say that it's a piece of reusable code.

The term actually came from the steel industries.

For a little bit of **history**, according to [Wikipedia](https://web.archive.org/web/20040619182702/http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate):

> In the 1890s, boilerplate was actually cast or stamped in metal ready for the printing press and distributed to newspapers around the United States. Until the 1950s, thousands of newspapers received and used this kind of boilerplate from the nation's largest supplier, the Western Newspaper Union. Some companies also sent out press releases as boilerplate so that they had to be printed as written.

Now according to [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Boilerplate_code&oldid=692410470):

> In object-oriented programs, classes are often provided with methods for getting and setting instance variables. The definitions of these methods can frequently be regarded as boilerplate. Although the code will vary from one class to another, it is sufficiently stereotypical in structure that it would be better generated automatically than written by hand. For example, in the following Java class representing a pet, almost all the code is boilerplate except for the declarations of Pet, name and owner:
>
> ```
> public class Pet {
>     private PetName name;
>     private Person owner;
>
>     public Pet(PetName name, Person owner) {
>         this.name = name;
>         this.owner = owner;
>     }
>
>     public PetName getName() {
>         return name;
>     }
>
>     public void setName(PetName name) {
>         this.name = name;
>     }
>
>     public Person getOwner() {
>         return owner;
>     }
>
>     public void setOwner(Person owner) {
>         this.owner = owner;
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 63):

On the etymology the term *boilerplate*: from http://www.takeourword.com/Issue009.html...

> Interestingly, the term arose from the newspaper business.   Columns
>   and other pieces that were syndicated were sent out to subscribing
>   newspapers in the form of a mat (i.e. a matrix).  Once received,
>   boiling lead was poured into this mat to create the plate used to
>   print the piece, hence the name boilerplate.  As the article printed
>   on a boilerplate could not be altered, the term came to be used by
>   attorneys to refer to the portions of a contract which did not change
>   through repeated uses in different applications, and finally to
>   language in general which did not change in any document that was used
>   repeatedly for different occasions.

What constitutes boilerplate in programming? As may others have pointed out, it
is just a chunk of code that is copied over and over again with little or
no changes made to it in the process.

Comment: There is an alternative explanation http://mentalfloss.com/article/26087/why-it-boilerplate-text for which I have seen more references.

Comment: damn! this seems like an answer for a grammar stackexchange...actually maybe this entire question, but I can see why we need it here...

Answer (score 45):

It's code that can be used by many applications/contexts with little or no change.

Boilerplate is derived from the steel industry in the early 1900s.

Answer (score 41):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code):

> In computer programming, boilerplate is the term used to describe sections of code that have to be included in many places with little or no alteration. It is more often used when referring to languages that are considered verbose, i.e. the programmer must write a lot of code to do minimal jobs.

So basically you can consider *boilerplate code* as a text that is needed by a programming language very often all around the programs you write in that language.

Modern languages are trying to reduce it, but also the older language which has specific type-checkers (for example OCaml has a type-inferrer that allows you to avoid so many declarations that would be boilerplate code in a more verbose language like Java)

Answer (score 31):

Boilerplate is what good programmers avoid: repetition.

Comment: OMG, you have "ti" twice in your answer! As you can see, repetition is not *always* bad.

Comment: How do I avoid `public static void main(String[] _)` ?

Comment: @KorayTugay Some times boilerplate is not easy to avoid. For example, you can avoid to repeat main function in your project by using only one and manage your whole project with it. In web development we could avoid the html5 template in each page by using single page development. In Android we could avoid the Activity boilerplate by using single Activity.

Answer (score 21):

Boilerplate in software development can mean different things to different people but generally means the block of code that is used over and over again.

In *MEAN* stack development, this term refers to code generation through use of template. It's easier than hand coding the entire application from scratch and it gives the code block consistency and fewer bugs as it is clean, tested and proven code and it's open source so it is constantly getting updated or fixed therefore it saves a lot of time as using framework or code generator. For more information about MEAN stack, click [here](http://mean.io/).

Answer (score 13):

Boilerplate definition is becoming more global in many other programming languages nowadays. It comes from OOP and hybrid languages that have become OOP and were before procedual have now the same goal to keep repeating the code you build with a model/template/class/object hence why they adapt this term. You make a template and the only things you do for each instance of a template are the parameters to individualize an object this part is what we call boilerplate. You simply re-use the code you made a template of, just with different parameters.

**Synonyms**
a blueprint is a boilerplate
a stencil is a boilerplate
a footer is a boilerplate
a design pattern for multiple use is a boilerplate
 
a signature of a mail is a boilerplate

Answer (score 8):

In practical terms, boilerplate code is the stuff you cut-n-paste all over the place.  Often it'll be things like a module header, plus some standard/required declarations (every module must declare a logger, every module must declare variables for its name and revision, etc.)  On my current project, we're writing message handlers and they all have the same structure (read a message, validate it, process it) and to eliminate dependencies among the handlers we didn't want to have them all inherit from a base class, so we came up with a boilerplate skeleton.  It declared all the routine variables, the standard methods, exception handling framework — all a developer had to do was add the code specific to the message being handled.  It would have been quick & easy to use, but then we found out we were getting our message definitions in a spreadsheet (which used a boilerplate format), so we wound up just writing a code generator to emit 90% of the code (including the unit tests).

Answer (score 8):

In a nutshell, boilerplate codes are repetitive codes required to be included in the application with little to no change by the program/framework, and contribute nothing to the logic of the application. When you write pseudo codes you can remove boilerplate codes. The recommendation is to use a proper Editor that generates boilerplate codes.

in HTML, the boilerplate codes in the interface.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html>   
   <head>   
      <title></title>   
   </head>   
   <body> </body>   
</html>
```

in C#, The boilerplate codes of properties.

```
class Price
{   
  private string _price;   
  public string Price
  {   
     get {return _price;}   
     set {_price= value;}   
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[Joshua Bloch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch) has a [talk about API design](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAb7hSCtvGw) that covers how bad ones make boilerplate code necessary.  (Minute 46 for reference to boilerplate, listening to this today)

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to it as "snippets" or more accurately "collection of snippets" .
The term I think was coined from the press and printing industry, where they used actual "plates" and then re-used them as chunks again..
In modern-day internet it is a part of an ongoing (annoying IMHO) trend of using fancy terms for simple things in order to look more trendy and sophisticated . see RESPONSIVE = adaptable / fluid.

Comment: "Snippets" doesn't quite convey the same meaning; "boilerplate" tends to connote bigger chunks that are meant to be modified to fit, as opposed to a couple lines of copy/paste/forget code. An example might be code for the `WinMain` function in a Win32 app; it registers the app's window class, creates the main window, runs the event loop, and returns the window procedure's exit code. That functionality often doesn't change much between apps, and can be reused with relatively few modifications, but is not so routine that it makes much sense as a library (or a snippet, for that matter).

Answer (score 3):

From [**whatis.techtarget.com**](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/boilerplate) :

> In information technology, a boilerplate is a unit of writing that can
>   be reused over and over without change. By extension, the idea is
>   sometimes applied to reusable programming as in "boilerplate code."
>   The term derives from steel manufacturing, where boilerplate is steel
>   rolled into large plates for use in steam boilers. The implication is
>   either that boilerplate writing has been time-tested and strong as
>   "steel," or possibly that it has been rolled out into something strong
>   enough for repeated reuse.

Beyond programming :

> A boilerplate can be compared to a certain kind of template, which can
>   be thought of as a fill-in-the-blanks boilerplate. Some typical
>   boilerplates include: mission statements, safety warnings, commonly
>   used installation procedures, copyright statements, and responsibility
>   disclaimers.

In my experience as a programmer, the proper kind of boilerplate code is typically a bunch of code that you start off with that's not large and/or complicated enough to be called a framework.

A typical example would be the [**HTML5 Boilerplate**](https://html5boilerplate.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Repeatable sections of code which just adds an unnecessary layer of typing to get the job done.

##### Are these necessary?

For the most part, these are structural and decorative markups. It provides consistency on how a code, function, language could look like.

So its kind of redundant as developers because we have seen it multiple times, but does convey some actual meaning to non-developers and compilers.