# Closing statement after database operation?

Tags: java, jdbc

Statement statement;
Connection connection;

I am closing connection after every database operation as below.

```
connection.close();
```

i created statement object as below.

```
connection.createStatement(....)
```

Do i need to close satement also similar to connection closing?

**I mean do i need to call statement.close();?**

What will happen if it is not called?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225221/closing-database-connections-in-java

Comment: There is a simmilar post. I hope it helps.

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507440/must-jdbc-resultsets-and-statements-be-closed-separately-although-the-connection

Comment: One problem with just closing the connection and not closing the result set (or `connection.createStatement()`), is that if your *connection management code* is using **connection pooling** then the `connection.close()` would just put the connection back in the *pool*. Additionally, some databases have a *cursor resource* on the server that will not be freed (released) properly unless it is **explicitly** closed.

Comment: @Lion, good comment.  Also, if you are not using connection management, consider keeping the connection and re-using it when feasible to do so.  It can take a long time to re-establish a connection.  (Logging in in is the second slowest operation in databases.  The slowest is logging out.)

Comment: @Lion Any decent connection pool will close resources that were created for a logical connection when the physical connection is returned to the pool (maybe with the exception of a pooled Statement, but then that wouldn't be closed either when the logical Statement object is closed).

Answer (score 5):

The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29) says it all:

> `Statement.close()`
>
> Releases this Statement object's database and JDBC resources immediately instead of waiting for this to happen when it is automatically closed. **It is generally good practice to release resources as soon as you are finished with them to avoid tying up database resources.**

One good way to ensure that `close()` is always called is by placing it inside a `finally` block:

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
try {
    // use `stmt'
} finally {
    stmt.close();
}
```

In Java 7, the above can be more concisely written as:

```
try (Statement stmt = connection.createStatement()) {
    // ...
}
```

This is called the [`try`-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: Or, if using Java 7, to use the try-with-resources construct. See the end of this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks for the suggestion! I've added this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general if you close a connection, all associated resources will be closed as well, provided the driver implementer did his work correctly. That said: it is better to close resources when your done with them, as that will free up resources both on your side and the database.