# Do I need to close 'PreparedStatement'?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a website which is getting a massive number of hits. I'm experienced problems, including JDBC connection errors.

I'm a bit confused about closing `PreparedStatement`. Do I need to close `PreparedStatement` or is it just enough to only close `Statement`?

Also, what about `ResultSet`? Do I need to close it too?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: Posible Duplicate of [Closing Database Connections in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225221/closing-database-connections-in-java)

Comment: Show your statement here about which you are asking

Comment: As [the official tutorial closes PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) it's safe to assume you have to close them I guess..

Comment: Are you talking about closing the `Statement` or `Connection`? Why shall closing an `Statement` handle closing a non-related `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: See also [Must JDBC Resultsets and Statements be closed separately although the Connection is closed afterwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507440/must-jdbc-resultsets-and-statements-be-closed-separately-although-the-connection)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, you have to close the prepared statements (`PreparedStatement` Object) and result sets as they may cause memory leakage.

For more information, see *[Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)*.

Comment: No, it is enough to close the `Connection` only, which closes all `Statements` and `PreparedStatements` created from it, and `ResultSets` created in turn from them, but if you're using a lot of `PreparedStatements` and `ResultSets` *per connection* it would be *wise* to close them as soon as possible. There is nothing in your link that supports your claim.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you must close it. If the connection from a pool, closing it actually sends it back to the pool for reuse.

Close in the `finally{}` block, such that if an exception is thrown, you still get the chance to close this.

Comment: Isn't that related to calling close on the connection object rather than on the statement object though ?