# is it possible to pull selected row from database by jsp and Servlets?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

i am using the following query to pull selected data

```
String fetch_head = "select * from head_category where id = (?)";
```

but i don't know how to pull row by ResultSet and supply parameter using PreparedStatement same time.

```
public ArrayList fetch_selected() {
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        try {
            connectionFactory cf = new connectionFactory();
            con = cf.getcon();
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(fetch_head);

            while (rs.next()) {
                // it only fetches all              
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
```

Now where do I put the PreparedStatement...?

Answer (score 0):

`st` isn't declare in your code and it should be `PreparedStatement`

```
PreparedStatement  st = con.createStatement();
```

Notice that you must [release all resources as PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546592/do-i-need-to-close-preparedstatement)  in your code