# Do I need to close sql2o queries

Tags: java, jdbc, garbage-collection, sql2o

A few months back I learned that when working with `java.sql.connection` I needed to close `PreparedStatements` and `ResultSet` to prevent memory leakage, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546592/do-i-need-to-close-preparedstatement)

However I recently started working with a new team that uses `org.sql2o.connection` which is a nice and useful jdbc wrapper, but I noticed that they don't usually close their `org.sql2o.Query` objects.

```
try(org.sql2o.Connection c = Sql2oObject.open()){
    //...some logic
    List<SomeClass> list = c.createQuery(sql).executeAndFetch(SomeClass.class);
    //...some more logic
}
```

As you can see the query object is never explicitly closed. I think that it would be better to close the query as well as such:

```
try(org.sql2o.Connection c = sql2oObject.open();
    org.sql2o.Query q = c.createQuery(sql); ) {
    //...some logic
    List<SomeClass> list = q.executeAndFetch(SomeClass.class);
    //...some more logic
}
```

But I'm not sure if it is really necessary. If it is, then I've found a major probable leak and I will be regarded as a genius and remembered throughout the eternity. If is not, then I'm just a guy asking for an unnecessary change.

So, what do you say oh mighty SO? is it necessary to close them?

Answer (score 0):

Not really you have to call close as the way you have used the `sql2o.connection` as you are using it with [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) approach in Java.

What it does in try-with-resource java is compiler adds the `finally` statement for your code where you suppose to close the native resource explicitly. Otherwise you must close the  `sql2o.connection` inside a finally block. Since its a jdbc wrapper around the standard `jdbc connection`

If you want to close other underline resources as well with try-with-resource  declare them all in the parenthesis. So that it will close underline resources together with your main resource.
However in your case `Query` does not needs to be closed explicitly since its always part of the `sql2o.connection`