# Closing JDBC-Connections only in finally-block?

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

Why are database connections often closed at two positions, once directly after use, and secondly additionally in a finally-block using a check for null in order to prevent them to be closed twice. Doesn't it suffice to use the finally block? The finally-block is to be executed in every case.

Here is an official example of [Apache-Tomcat JNDI Datasource HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html). They point out there that a connection MUST be closed under every circumstance. I wonder why it is not sufficient to use the finally-block as the close-commands within the end of the main try {}-block seem to be redundent.

```
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null; // Or PreparedStatement if needed
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try
    {
        conn = ... get connection from connection pool ...
        stmt = conn.createStatement("select ...");
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        ... iterate through the result set ...
        rs.close ();
        rs = null;
        stmt.close ();
        stmt = null;
        conn.close (); // Return to connection pool
        conn = null; // Make sure we don't close it twice
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        ... deal with errors ...
    }
    finally
    {
        // Always make sure result sets and statements are closed,
        // and the connection is returned to the pool
        if (rs != null)
        {
            try
            {
                rs.close ();
            }
            catch (SQLException ignore)
            {
            }
            rs = null;
        }
        if (stmt != null)
        {
            try
            {
                stmt.close ();
            }
            catch (SQLException ignore)
            {
            }
            stmt = null;
        }
        if (conn != null)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.close ();
            }
            catch (SQLException ignore)
            {
            }
            conn = null;
        }
    }
```

I would like to write much shorter:

```
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null; // Or PreparedStatement if needed
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try
    {
        conn = ... get connection from connection pool ...
        stmt = conn.createStatement ("select ...");
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        ... iterate through the result set ...
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        // ... deal with errors ...
    }
    finally
    {
        // Always make sure result sets and statements are closed,
        // and the connection is returned to the pool
        try
        {
            if (rs != null)
                rs.close ();
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close ();
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close ();
        }
        catch (SQLException ignore)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's the first time I see this. All examples I have encountered are doing it only in the finally block. I don't think this is a very popular practice. I think it adds overhead and complexity to the code.

Comment: Or even shorter with `try-with-resources` ;) But yeah, the example seems overly complicated.

Comment: What if `rs.close()` throws an exception in your code? Then `stmt` and `conn` won't be closed.

Comment: right! one should put all the three closing-commands as in the Apache-example in three independent try-catch-blocks.

Comment: The Tomcat sample code is poor quality, but yours isn't an improvement. The correct solution from Java 7 is to use try-with-resources.

Comment: Not to overlook that closing a `Statement` closes all associated `ResultSets,` and closing a `Connection` closes all associated `Statements` ... so two-thirds of your suggested `finally` block is redundant anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a good question - I don't understand the "official example" either. Finally block is certainly enough.

However, your code has more serious faults, namely if rs.close() would throw an exception, you'd have `stmt` and `conn` leaking out and you'd also ignore that exception silently. That is something you should not do. Since Java 7, using try-with-resources construct is the preferred way, but if you cannot go there, at least handle each possible exception (rs, stmt, conn) separately so they don't cause each other to leak.

For example Apache commons DbUtils has [closeQuietly()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/DbUtils.html#closeQuietly%28java.sql.Connection%29) just for this purpose, because it used to be a common scenario. Personally I would go to somewhere like [Spring JDBCTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) that does this sort of stuff behind the scenes.

Edit: try-with-resources is explained by Oracle [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). In short, you'd do it something like this:

```
try (Connection conn = yourCodeToGetConnection();
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
        int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
        float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
        int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");
        int total = rs.getInt("TOTAL");

        System.out.println(coffeeName + ", " + supplierID + ", " + 
                               price + ", " + sales + ", " + total);
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    // log, report or raise
}
```

Where the try-statement automatically deals with `conn`, `stmt` and `rs` closing in all cases and in order (the reverse order in which you state them). Possible exceptions you still need to handle yourself.

Comment: could you please explain the try-with-resources construct? haven't heart about this so far.

Comment: @tombo_189 added a quick explanation

Comment: I never knew about try with resources. +1 for that.The official page's code seems confusing to me too.

Comment: @tombo_189 you might want to look at Spring's jdbc template.

Comment: @eis: Why haven't you put the Connection itself in a third try-with-resources block? Isn't the Connection the main thing to be closed?

Comment: You don't need three try-blocks, or even two.

Comment: Yes, connection itself should be in a similar block and yes, these things can be combined into the same try block. This was a very quick example I put together - I can add those.

Comment: [How should I use try-with-resources with JDBC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066501/how-should-i-use-try-with-resources-with-jdbc) has some nice ideas on how to do this when you need a `PreparedStatement` and bind variables.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the many comments. So summing up (especially EJP comments to my question [that closing a Connection will close underlying Statements and closing a Statement will it self close the ResultSet]) and as I consider the try-with-resource construct to be a bit difficult to read I suggest writing

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null; // Or PreparedStatement if needed
ResultSet rs = null;
try
{
    conn = ... get connection from connection pool ...
    stmt = conn.createStatement ("select ...");
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    ... iterate through the result set ...
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
    // ... deal with errors ...
}
finally
{
    // Always make sure result sets and statements are closed,
    // and the connection is returned to the pool
    try
    {
        if (conn != null)
            conn.close ();
    }
    catch (SQLException ignore)
    {
    }
}
```

and closing only the main Connection while leaving the Statement and the ResultSet always untouched and to be closed by the Connection.

Right?

Comment: Well, this can be a subject of debate which you can get to in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507440/must-jdbc-resultsets-and-statements-be-closed-separately-although-the-connection). Normally Connection will close the others, but AFAIK it's not guaranteed. IMO It's easier to just let either try-with-resources, JDBCTemplate or similar to make sure the things are closed. But I'm not claiming this is wrong either. Also, personally I'd at least log if there are any SQLExceptions, even if you don't raise them.

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer writing a common method for closing the connection, which can be called from a finally block.

Something like this:

```
Connection conn = null;        
Statement stmt = null; // Or PreparedStatement if needed        
ResultSet rs = null;

try
{
    conn = ... get connection from connection pool ...            
    stmt = conn.createStatement ("select ...");         
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();

    ... iterate through the result set ...

}
catch (SQLException e)
{
    // ... deal with errors ...
}
finally
{
    CloseTheConnection(conn);        
    CloseTheStatement(stmt);         
}

public void closeTheConnection(Connection conn){             
try{
    if(conn!=null){            
     conn.close();             
  }             
}catch(Exception ex){            
}

public void closeTheStatement(Statement stmt){             
try{            
 if( stmt != null)            
      stmt.close();            
  } catch(Exception ex){                
  }
}
```

By creating different methods and calling them from finally will ensure that even if you get any exception from one method the other method will definitely be called. And it will be reusable as well.

Comment: mind the whitespace in your code... I fixed the code block but you should really fix whitespace yourself to be readable and consistent

Comment: ya sure,this is my first answer here,was struggling to even post :D. will take care of that :)