# Warning missing release resource eclipse setting

Tags: java, eclipse

I have missing about close PreparedStatement in code.
I want to find all function same problem => How to setting warning missing release resource in eclipse?
I try to **Window -> Preference -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warning -> Resource Leak** but it not active.

```
 private void insertData(String userName)
        throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ps = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_DATA);
    ps.setString(1, userName);
    // SQL execution
    ps.executeUpdate();

}
```

Thank all

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example code.
I think you have to set the **potential resource leak** to warning or error to see the PreparedStatement issues you like to find.

this is because a PreparedStatement might be closed when the connection is closed.

See a discussion about that here: [Must JDBC Resultsets and Statements be closed separately although the Connection is closed afterwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507440/must-jdbc-resultsets-and-statements-be-closed-separately-although-the-connection)