# How can I display all rows of a count query in a javafx textarea? It is only diplaying the first row instead of two rows

Tags: javafx

I want the two rows of a count and groupby (sqlite)sql query to be displayed in the text area, but it is only displaying the first row.

When I place the `conn.close()` statement outside the "while" block, it displays only the second row and leaves out the first row

```
@FXML
private void viewResult(ActionEvent event)
{
    try
    {
        Connection conn = dbConnection.getConnection();
        Statement resultStmt = conn.createStatement();   
        ResultSet rs = resultStmt.executeQuery("select candidate, count(candidate) from voteResult group by candidate");
        while (rs.next()) {
            String news = rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2);
            this.result.setText(news);
            conn.close();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Error " + e);
    }

}
```

the expected result should be like this:

```
JOSEPH THANKGOD 4
ORJI DANIEL 1
```

Comment: Edit your post using code formatting.

Comment: What is the current String you get when you execute your code?

Answer (score 6):

Each time you call `setText(String value)` the previous value will be overwritten. So you have to build your result string first and set it as content of the `TextArea` afterwards. I don't know how exactly `Connection` and the other components work together but i guess if you close your `Connection` in the first while-loop-cycle the `ResultSet` won't be usable to get the next row anymore. Moreover, calling the `close` method of `Connection` the second or third time will not cause anything to happen because it is a no-op if the `Connection` object is already closed.

```
@FXML
private void viewResult(ActionEvent event) {

    // Open resources with try-with-resources block
    try (Connection conn = dbConnection.getConnection();
        Statement resultStmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = resultStmt.executeQuery("select candidate, count(candidate) from voteResult group by candidate");){

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while (rs.next()) {
            // Append each row
            builder.append(rs.getString(1)).append(" ").append(rs.getString(2)).append("\n");
        }

        // Remove last newline character
        if (builder.length() > 0) {
            builder.setLength(builder.length() - 1);
        }

        // Get complete string and set as TextArea content
        this.result.setText(builder.toString());

    // Resources will be closed automatically due to try-with-resources
    }
}
```

Besides you shouldn't mix UI and database code and should use the try-with-resources block (take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15728512/7380097)).

Comment: Your code perfectly solved the problem. The only bug in it was sb which I understood to be the builder variable. I'm very grateful.

Comment: You are right, I have fixed it. I'm happy that I could help you! It would be nice if you could accept the answer :)

Comment: Your answer was perfect.