# Python joblib - get result of parallel calculations on Windows machine

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

Here is my code:

```
from math import sqrt
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

def parallel_calc():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        result = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(sqrt)(i ** 2) for i in range(10))
        return result

result = parallel_calc()
print(result[-1])
```

It generates error message: `print(result[-1]) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. In addition, it does not terminate.

Since I am on Window 7, I have to use this check `if __name__ == '__main__':`, but how do I get result from `parallel_calc` function?

Answer (score 2):

Move the `if __name__...`, or `boilerplate`, outside of your function scope.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    def parallel_calc():
        result = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(sqrt)(i ** 2) for i in range(10))
        return result

    result = parallel_calc()
    print(result[-1])
```

Since your `parallel_calc` function does not reside within the `boilerplate`, it is being called twice.

The error is coming from the `Parallel` process not being executed the first time it is called, returning `None`

Take a look at ["Boilerplate code in Python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898049/boilerplate-code-in-python) for more information on the `boilerplates`